# Can I use one SimpleDateFormat pattern for dates with both 'Z' and '+1:00' suffixes?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, dst

I call a service which returns GMT dates.  Its been working fine since November, but now with daylight savings time active, its failing.  Here's a sample date from  non-daylight savings time:

```
2011-12-07T15:50:01Z
```

And one from today (in daylight savings time):

```
2012-03-26T11:05:01+01:00
```

Previously I've been using this pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.UK);
```

But its failing on the second date above with a ParseExcepton ("Unparsable date...").  So, can one pattern be used for both, and if so what is it?  If I can't use one pattern for both, what is the correct pattern for the second date above?

It shouldn't make a difference, but if it does this is in use on the Android platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely makes a difference that you're using Android, as it would make a difference in this case if you were using Java 5/6 or 7.

The pattern you're using specifies a literal 'Z' (also 'T') to be parsed. It is not parsing a timezone. You need to drop the single-quotes from around the 'Z' to start parsing an actual time-zone.

According to the [Android JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it is unclear whether a capital Z will even work in this case, as the format of the hours/minutes is pretty specific. I don't know enough about the Android SDK to confirm, but the colon definitly makes a difference in standard Java.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, Should have known it wouldn't be a straightforward answer!  I've tried dropping the single quotes around the 'Z' and it now works on the second date (after removing the ':') but not the first. Looks like I need to conditionally choose which date format to parse with.

Comment: No, just replace `Z` at the end (if it exists) with `+01:00` before parsing the date. `Z` is the symbol for this offset.

Answer (score 2):

The new ISO8601 time zone pattern is covered by the `X` pattern specifier which is introduced in [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.UK);
```

If you're still on [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or older, then yes it may make difference. You'll need either to parse it (partially) yourself or to grab [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 1):

In case you use java6, you will have to identify the patterns and then apply the formater

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    String date2Str="2011-12-07T15:50:01Z";
    Date date2 = df.parse(date2Str);
    System.out.println(date2.toString());

    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");
    String date1Str="2012-03-26T11:05:01GMT+01:00";
    Date date1 = df2.parse(date1Str);

    System.out.println(date1.toString());
```